# How to detect country code

Tags: android

HI All I am working on an app.What I want to achieve is on receiving phone call I want to detect country code from the phone number and also from which country I am receiving call.Can anybody help me.???

Comment: see this https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso%28%29

Comment: thanks for your answer in your reference example can u explain this line of code PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH"); what is the meaning of second argument "CH" ? its a country specific ? and kindly tell me how I can test international call on my phone is there any way so that I can make any test call to my device

Comment: @MeMalik That is the country code for Switzerland.

Comment: @PankajKumar yes here we are bound to provide a country code Like "CH"  n "PK" and "IND" so is there any way so that we can detect run time i.e upon receiving call ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done with libphonenumber library [Get the country code](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)

Comment: thanks for your answer in your reference example can u explain this line of code
`PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");`
what is the meaning of second argument "CH" ? its a country specific ? and kindly tell me how I can test international call on my phone is there any way so that I can make any test call to my device